# How to turn on Firefox's Responsive Design Mode's touch simulator?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I want to use Firefox for mobile development. And I would like to turn on Firefox's responsive design's touch simulator.

While I'm in device mode in Chrome, the browser shows a gray circle as mouse cursor and I can drag (slide) my page:

[image: Device mode in Chrome]

But in Firefox's Responsive Design Mode I see the normal arrow cursor and can't drag the page:

[image: Responsive Design Mode in Firefox]

Is there maybe a preference for this in `about:config`?

Comment: The items in the fotos are difficult to see. You should replace them by normal screenshots.

Comment: @SebastianZartner, to my regret on normal screenshots we could see mouse cursor

Comment: I've replaced them by proper screenshots (including the cursors).

Answer (score 3):

The touch event simulation available via [image: touch event simulation button] currently (as of Firefox 51.0.1) only [translates mouse events into touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode#Toggling_touch_event_simulation).

It doesn't provide mobile gestures like dragging to scroll ([bug 1282089](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1282089)), nor shows a circle as cursor ([bug 1271728](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1271728)). So, this feature is very restricted at the moment.

Comment: thanks. As U could see on the second pic in my post I enabled touch simulation(in my FF 52 Developer Edition). I thought there were troubles on my sight. Now I see there are 2 bugs((

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit stuck with this today, too. Luckily, I found that with a wheeled mouse I'm able to move the page up and down (scroll the wheel) and sideways (press the wheel left or right).  I have Firefox Quantum 64.0 (64-bit) on Windows. Mouse cursor still does not indicate the abilities at any way.